# Python 3 code while loop wrong output

Tags: python

It's written in python 3. The code is trying to store all the input integers into a list and find the min, max and average. What causes the output average to be wrong here?

```
from statistics import mean, median
def main():
    integers = []
    integer = 0
    while (1):    
        input_str = input('Enter a value (0 to end): ')
        try:
            integer = int(input_str)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Type a legit integer.')
        if integer == 0:
            if integers == []:
                print('No integer stored.')

            else:
                print('Min: {0}\nMax: {1}\nAvg: {2:.1f}\n'.format(min(integers),max(integers),sum(integers)/len(integers)))
            break
        elif integer >= -65535 and integer <= 65535:
            integers.append(integer)
        else:
            print('The integer is out of range.')
main()
```

The output is:

```
Enter a value (0 to end): 110
Enter a value (0 to end): 60
Enter a value (0 to end): abc
Invalid input. Type a legit integer.
Enter a value (0 to end): 50
Enter a value (0 to end): 90
Enter a value (0 to end): 40
Enter a value (0 to end): hanbagui
Invalid input. Type a legit integer.
Enter a value (0 to end): 0
Min: 40
Max: 110
Avg: 64.3
```

Comment: Don't post code as an image, give it as text.

Comment: Don't forget to take a  [Tour] as a new user.

Comment: As these other users have said, include the code here.
That said, try printing the integers list to see what it looks like at the end. I think the issue has something to do with integers not being reset when you give an incorrect input.

Comment: I don't see why this code wouldn't work. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you meet an error, you should **ignore the next code segments** and avoid to execute the next lines, or you will continue to running next lines and something happend accidentially.

so you should add code do **jump** when `ValueError` happens.

```
try:
            integer = int(input_str)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Type a legit integer.')
            continue #important
```